# showing image in templates using django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. My project folder contain media folder. It contain some images.

How can I display this images in template of another app?

Path : *mysite/media/blog/templates/blog/details.html*

details.html

```
{{<img src="media/image_2.jpg">}}
```

But it does not display anything..

Comment: in my details.html page I am trying <img src="media/image_2.jpg">

Comment: Why would you put that in a template tag?

Comment: It's a hard-coded piece of HTML. Why do you think you have to put it in anything? Just place it in your template.

Comment: Actually I was trying to display an image which is uploaded through admin..I was trying this code:<img src="{{MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.image }}">  but it did not work..so I used to try the first one..

Answer (score 0):

You should set-up the STATIC folder and to configure the media files.

The full reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ and also
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/.

However you should use something like this (once you configured properly the STATIC files) :

```
<img src="{% static "media/myexample.jpg" %}"/>
```

**Edit:**
Before using `static` tag, You must load specific tags incluing on top of template code: `{% load staticfiles %}` : [Referring to static files in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-in-templates)